# ntldr corrupted, fix without cds

Tags: windows-server-2003, ntldr

My Windows Server 2003 (HP ProLiant ML115) turned off and now shows that the NTLDR is corrupted.

I know that I supposedly can repair it with the installation CDs, sadly it turns out that, at the time, the seller didn't gave me all the CDs (just the 2-3-4 out of 5). There is, in another CD, a bootable recovery that get stuck just after loading the image.

How can I fix my ntldr file with this limitation? 
Is there any particular thing I have to check since my hdd are in RAID (using NVidia RAID5 technology) ?

Comment: Can you not restore from your backup? Also I need to add the standard warning about Server 2003 being unsupported and you should consider an upgrade path.

Comment: We should have backup, but they are old. I'm asking right now since it's my father server, I'm asking on his behalf. We where about to start a new back up system because the one he used to have was too slow and too pricy. My idea for the moment is to buy an hard disk, boot up linux from usb, recover all file and restore wathever back up he should have.

Comment: Depending on what type of backup you have, it might be able to restore just the MBR and ntldr.    In any case, there should be a way to get a copy of those CDs.  I would contact Microsoft about this if my backup scheme doesn't work out..